In Blazor StateHasChanged Used in a Delegate method Only Updates The Component Sometimes
I am running a longish process and have a simple text to update the status on the page for each step of the process (i.e. "Step 1 of 7: Downloading data"). I'm using async methods and have an event callback / delegate to trigger the status text update. The first couple of times invoking the delegate method do update the text just fine, but then the rest don't update on the page until the very last one. The delegate method is invoked every time expect it to (I can put a break point in there and the text is correct)
Can anyone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong? Why, even when I call StateHasChanged does it decide to not update the component after the first couple of times? Have I gotten into a thread nightmare or something?
This is using Blazor Hybrid in a MAUI app if that's relevant.
My Page's Status Text Markup:
<p>@StatusText</p>

My Page's Code:
public partial class SyncMetadata {

  public string StatusText { get; set; }


  protected override void OnInitialized()
  {
    base.OnInitialized();
  }

  protected override async void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
  {
    base.OnAfterRender(firstRender);
    if (firstRender)
    {
      MetadataSyncService syncService = new MetadataSyncService();
      syncService.StatusUpdated += UpdateStatus;
      string status = await syncService.SyncMetadata();
      UpdateStatus(this, status); // this one does get shown properly on the page at the end
    }
  }


// THIS IS THE DELEGATE METHOD THAT UPDATES THE TEXT
// If I put a breakpoint in here it does get invoked every time I expect it to with the correct statusText
  public void UpdateStatus(object? sender, string statusText)
  {
    StatusText = statusText;
    InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
  }

}

The MetadataSyncService that does the work and invokes the delegate from the page to update the status text:
public class MetadataSyncService {


  public event EventHandler<string>? StatusUpdated;


  public async Task<string> SyncMetadata()
  {
    try
    {
      HttpCommunication http = new HttpCommunication();
      string statusText = "Downloading lookup data";
      OnStatusUpdated(statusText);
      statusText = await http.FetchLookupData(Enums.LookupDataSyncType.Other);
      statusText = "Downloading user specific data";
      OnStatusUpdated(statusText);
      statusText = await http.FetchLookupData(Enums.LookupDataSyncType.OrganizationSpecific);

// EVERYTHING IS FINE UP TO HERE. The status text on the page is updated with the first 2 statuses ("Downloading lookup data" and "Downloading user specific data")

      OnStatusUpdated(statusText);  // this update doesn't show on the page
      statusText = "test 1";        // this update doesn't show on the page either
      OnStatusUpdated(statusText);
      statusText = UnpackAndUpdateLookupData(); // this method has several updates that don't show on the page, but are invoked exactly as others before. It's rather long so I'm not showing it and I don't think it's relevant to the question since there are already updates before it that don't work.
      return statusText; 
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      return GetFormattedErrorMessage(ex.Message);
    }
  }


  protected virtual void OnStatusUpdated(string statusText)
  {
    StatusUpdated?.Invoke(this, statusText);
  }
}

I've tried many things including:

Removing all the async so everything was just synchronous (that
resulted in NO updates)
Moving the code from the OnAfterRender to a button event in case the
lifecycle was messing it up
Moving all the code from the SyncMetadata method directly in line in
the page's code
StateHasChange() rather than InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged)

EDIT: I posted my own answer, but haven't marked it as the solution because it feels a little hacky. I'm still interested to see if anyone has an idea for a better way to handle it than I came up with.

Please override the OnAfterRenderAsync instead of OnAfterRender if you want to run async code in it.
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
  {
    base.OnAfterRender(firstRender);
    if (firstRender)
    {
      MetadataSyncService syncService = new MetadataSyncService();
      syncService.StatusUpdated += UpdateStatus;
      StatusText = await syncService.SyncMetadata();
    }
  }

When you use async void, UI is never refreshed (re-rendered) because it didn't know when the async methods called return. But the Task will let the runtime know when the method return. So use async Task instead of async void.

I found someone who helped me understand.
This was his explanation: The main thread that updates the UI needs to have some sort of "break" where it is able to update the UI. In my case the first two status updates invoking the Event were able to update the UI because immediately after them was an "await" that, once completed, provided the "break" that the main thread needed to update the UI, but all of my invocations of the event after that didn't have any "break" for the UI thread to update. I guess that when an async Task completes it interjects into the main thread letting it know it's done and that the main thread may need to do something now and that provides the opportunity to process the StateHasChanged() call.
So while I don't know if this is the best solution I was able to get my case working by making my OnStatusUpdated method async and slipping in an await immediately after invoking the event that updates the UI.
protected virtual async Task OnStatusUpdated(string statusText)
{
  StatusUpdated?.Invoke(this, statusText);
  await Task.Delay(1);
}

